# Correct use of session and static variables

Tags: c#, session, static

I apologize in advance since I see this topic discussed many times, yet I remain uncertain I got it right.

All I wish is to have a session specific set of variables of a class type, that I can define and use across pages and postbacks but not between other users of the website.

I'm a long time programmer but minimally skilled in C#, and I wish to make sure this code is what those of you with experience would find acceptable:

```
public static class MySessionVariables
{
    public class Emailaccountclass
    {
        public string emailAddress;
        public List<int?> seenAccountUIDs;
        public int inboxRecords;
        public int recordsInEmailSent;
    }
    public static Emailaccountclass SessionEmailAccounts
    {
        get { return HttpContext.Current.Session["SessionEmailAccounts"] as Emailaccountclass; }
        set { HttpContext.Current.Session["SessionEmailAccounts"] = value; }
    }
}
```

Comment: So what's the question here actually?

Comment: Yes looks ok to me. the only thing you want to add is a test to see if the session variable is NULL first before returning it but its not necessary if you are handling the property being NULL anyway

Comment: You don't actually have any static variables, just a static method.

Comment: I read about how it is dangerous to use static variables since they will be shared between users... yet the examples I have from Stackoverflow seem to use the public static you see in my example.above.  I also receive an error when I reach this statement              MySessionVariables.SessionEmailAccount.Add(new MySessionVariables.Emailaccountclass {emailAddress= "myemailaddress.com", seenAccountUIDs= null, inboxRecords= 0, recordsInEmailSent= 0 });  It says object reference is not set to an instance of the object

Comment: A static instance is created once for the whole lifetime of the program. A session object is created on demand at the server and is disposed after session end. I doubt you want to have any variable of type `static` in your session. You could use static methods though.